# Why the setter function is not running in this Kotlin program

Tags: kotlin, constructor, getter, setter

The following is the kotlin program. I have confusion that why the setter function is not being called on running line x.b=20.

```
class Num(value: Int) {
  var a = value + 4
  var b = value + 6
  var c = value + 1

  set(value) {
  println("field is : ${field}")
  field = value + b
  println("field is : ${field}")
  println("inside setter am here")
}
}
    
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
  var x = Num(3)
  x.b = 20
  println(x.b)
}
```

Comment: Can you include the whole class? Half seems to be missing.

Comment: Your setter is defined on `c`, but you're never setting `c`?

Answer (score 3):

It would be much clearer if your indentation were correct:

```
class Num(value: Int) {
  var a = value + 4
  var b = value + 6
  var c = value + 1
    set(value) {
      println("field is : ${field}")
      field = value + b
      println("field is : ${field}")
      println("inside setter am here")
    }
}
```

You have only defined a setter on `c`.  There is no way to make one setter for all the values, though factoring out a method might help.

Answer (score 0):

Louis explained why it's not working, but this statement:

> There is no way to make one setter for all the values

is not correct. It is possible by using [delegated properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/delegated-properties.html):

```
import kotlin.reflect.KProperty

class Num(value: Int) {
    var a by MySetter(value + 4)
    var b by MySetter(value + 6)
    var c by MySetter(value + 1)
}

class MySetter(private var field) {
    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Num, property: KProperty<*>) = field

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Num, property: KProperty<*>, value: Int) {
        println("field is : $field")
        field += value
        println("field is : $field")
        println("inside setter am here")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var x = Num(3)
    x.b = 20
    println(x.b)
}
```

This prints:

```
field is : 9
field is : 29
inside setter am here
29
```